# Get list of collection from firebase using flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

I need to get list of collection like

datalist = ["2009" , "2010"]

I can use this code to print what inside the 2009 , but that not i want

```
final _fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
Future<void> getData() async {
  // Get docs from collection reference
  QuerySnapshot querySnapshot =
      await _fireStore.collection('data/student_details/2009').get();

  // Get data from docs and convert map to List
  final allData = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();
  //for a specific field

  print(allData);
}
```

and I need to know about can I filter it

Thank you.

*My Firebase view*

[image: Firebase View]

Comment: student_details is a document not a collection

Comment: My suggestion, create  student_details collection at top level and get list of documents.

Comment: Ok, But some how I need to get list of what inside the student_details, how i do that

Answer (score 3):

In Firebase you can not fetch a list of Collections, You have to explicitly mention the name of Collection to fetch it. It means you must have pre-knowledge of name of Collection to fetch it.

Comment: But some time we cant get pre knowledge about it, So  what we can do for it

Comment: You might have to use cloud functions